# Vert.x JWT Not enough or too many segments

Tags: java, jwt, vert.x, keycloak

I am continually getting an error when my application receives a JWT token from the front end application, which is authenticating through KeyCloak. The error I am getting is "Not enough or too many segments". As far as I can tell, the token is a valid token and should be able to be verified, but I cannot get past this very generic error. Could someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the relevant snippet of code that is failing. Note that the same code works fine when running my test cases, which use the vert.x JWTAuth provider to generate a token:

```
JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JWTAuthOptions(new JsonObject()
    .put("permissionsClaimKey", "realm_access/roles")
    .put("pubSecKeys", new JsonObject()
            .put("publicKey", "vcVtWG5Qcz9gTMrDPfJSWNAiXsyCyBmNIzjtfHhBDX-l60KHyFaGBGBjRNkzDysV6pr6drQR8zRD8ePo8q73KDbXlZohXkR_J-gXer8H5EyWGl7KAATmKvuiYYv89f_C6f3NYUgfyKn6wzUtlsZN1CYpGmbnfLZYUcGzwvWWkddqQUroRrsf305Z17Pioegd_JMhcdprC1caOCuJHe46bYlu4_9m_MSPvBUCqjqAUIDZpB8HT9xrwxlwKG_Er6l-7TvQ32jp0wPxitLpEUg9noAt5w2NXIX44PCSkOdtGxGpj7fhyfivi_HQEfTq3Y4N2BRWAQxXYRaHlgl08CIsLb5rgJXmh8O7506V0THyLcJZ3pTn0u_4KxedOTsEbM_07W8kNCXVQrTIn4Zkyz42geRfblAzjvScP962DzEqu28WVZXWUyJIeQA_z3UM0l-MpQFtFDHsb0inQdeBfA6IN_eRp-JZaoMKLfswUEXjEj6nytKnwOEaqdqq56uPPK1j7QorIjMyn9VztH1WbbWM_JNPNc5CDAjFxo54tvrzqKkxLNbR1lP8g5GbIBeGSRc36IXQEp2hV42i3Pu-7bPJ_E0m9vr5dePjeRotthDUR7osmhOlzqHrLq1uzUYYneK37j7lLMx7N67rkWWMBa3v0h57pVD9ufAd-BxHiQzZL2U")
            .put("type", "RS256"))));

...

versionOneAPI.route().handler(ctx -> {
    String authHeader = ctx.request().getHeader("Authorization");
    String encodedToken = authHeader.substring(authHeader.indexOf(' ')+1);
    LOGGER.debug("Got the token {}", encodedToken);
    authProvider.authenticate(new JsonObject().put("jwt", encodedToken), res -> {
        LOGGER.debug("Request received for: {}", ctx.request().path());
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Got the user {} from the token", res.result().principal().getString("name"));
            ctx.setUser(res.result());
            ctx.response().putHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
            ctx.next();
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to parse token with {} segments", encodedToken.split("\\.").length, res.cause());
            ctx.response().setStatusCode(UNAUTHORIZED.code()).setStatusMessage(UNAUTHORIZED.reasonPhrase()).end();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a sample from the log showing the failure:

> 15:22:14.930 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - POST
>   http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/referrals 15:22:15.069
>   [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG com.redhat.rhambassador.MainVerticle
>   - Got the token eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJscVRYamlvRU9HbnBPenVLSllJOGs4VXFUTThSanBKOWc2bmVIb3pXVm9nIn0.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.ZWmsuIRsXeSdE_xefG_o-vYUZR4os_87jgd-7s9BC_-w1bHJ4K3tAIH3r_SxFS1hOYRxO3wsKniePkhcgfyHKDPpvSNc-HLsx3guARDGsdRiqEgszSoJTYvU_XRVcR8FEPPDs0vIov540A9mPPqpH4MPVK-dgZHH5IaSWpceeA91wmL5dh3Z-0nK5wIeFxDw-8PfzSzrF0crTG8Mr9KwaTr9iCTYta13kxIW3WU8xHe6qSYaQEJmKpj4y6YNtwdGvmVn9B9TngSBRliz-4nDj-WcVuWahkppSnuRgEEDsxFZ5DXvnKhK5j1aaU4HSamz7qd2UsgPya7DxpBHHIhcOp0fOzVcDJl4vm_zxnX7cO5Ulm4Vsn-Q5iFMHunXwtNkmxGxQrqWz24CYWF_CxMvcHgjK9pqGeJ6S43v2jQvTPA5dL6dcEhNOd6RH3dD7PJjhXN5b0MP-McjoJXoktnvNRLim_n2Dnsn-t3ceJhJVMqoYPvRd_F51Is1Rcuy3qzNRYtoeiHAkacHIzR5UxPheYtzyo0dtxz9dtHgd-WlWFFL4GyxRb5Ex6153JAZSK4neT4gAXldnSQqqDGHt1XZaeBR4G3l5bffozPuYCR9wDwtkNMI5VK5Q9o81mXdQen0DPt4XZgtSkQOoudNduZFhOy6GIzJAbiNifqJpOyud64
>   15:22:15.070 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG
>   com.redhat.rhambassador.MainVerticle - Request received for:
>   /rest/v1/referrals 15:22:15.072 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR
>   com.redhat.rhambassador.MainVerticle - Failed to parse token with 3
>   segments java.lang.RuntimeException: Not enough or too many segments
>     at io.vertx.ext.jwt.JWT.decode(JWT.java:321)    at
>   io.vertx.ext.auth.jwt.impl.JWTAuthProviderImpl.authenticate(JWTAuthProviderImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.redhat.rhambassador.MainVerticle.lambda$buildRoutes$7(MainVerticle.java:197)
>     at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:101)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:149)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.doEnd(BodyHandlerImpl.java:209)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.end(BodyHandlerImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.lambda$handle$0(BodyHandlerImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.handleEnd(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:418)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleLastHttpContent(ServerConnection.java:475)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleContent(ServerConnection.java:469)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.processMessage(ServerConnection.java:449)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleMessage(ServerConnection.java:156)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:705)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:614)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.lambda$channelRead$1(VertxHandler.java:150)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:342)
>     at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:148)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Which version of vertx are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the config JSON is not correct it should be:

```
JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JWTAuthOptions(new JsonObject()
.put("permissionsClaimKey", "realm_access/roles")
.put("pubSecKeys", new JsonArray()
   .add(new JsonObject()
      .put("publicKey", "...")
      .put("type", "RS256")))));
```

`pubSecKeys` is an array of objects. To be safer you probably should not use the JSON config but the typed one.

Comment: Thanks, although now I'm getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: RS256 not supported" is RS256 really not a supported algorithm?

Comment: That message is being bubbled because the provided key cannot be decoded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use vertx's jwt handler, it sets user to routing context and does authentication for you

```
JWTAuth jwtAuth = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JWTAuthOptions()
        .setPermissionsClaimKey("realm_access/roles")
        .addPubSecKey(new PubSecKeyOptions()
            .setType("RS256")
            .setPublicKey("....your key"));

router.route("/api/rest/a/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuth));
```